# problem with fetching records with select clause in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch a record in particular date range and which have particular title

for this, I am using below query

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` 
WHERE `page_title` = 'Surfshark Review: Should we Surf the Internet Ocean with this VPN? (2019)' 
  AND STR_TO_DATE(`datetime`, '%Y-%m-%d') 
        BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2019-09-16', '%Y-%m-%d') 
                AND STR_TO_DATE('2019-09-22', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

when I use this query it gives me null without any error but when I use below query

```
SELECT `page_title` 
FROM `table_name` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`datetime`, '%Y-%m-%d') 
        BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2019-09-16', '%Y-%m-%d') 
                AND STR_TO_DATE('2019-09-22', '%Y-%m-%d') 
GROUP BY `page_title`;
```

it shows me the "Surfshark Review: Should we Surf the Internet Ocean with this VPN? (2019)" within the records, I don't know why this happens.

can anybody help me with this.

Comment: Try using `like` and `upper`

Comment: I have already tried like Claus SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `page_title` LIKE '%Surfshark Review%' AND STR_TO_DATE(`datetime`, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2019-09-16', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2019-09-22', '%Y-%m-%d')  but it still not working

Comment: @ArifSherKhan  and why I need to use upper in this query can you explain?

Comment: upper(page_title) = upper(your_statement_in_upper_case). It is always a good practice to convert the both to either `upper/lower`. It reduces the probability of having  mismatching in string. Assume, `Test_String` is actual value in column, but in `where` clause you ended up writing `test_String` by mistake. This will cause row to get excluded. `Upper/Lower`  will remove this probability of mistakes,

Comment: @ArifSherKhan thank you for explaining this. I have tried to use UPPER in this query:- SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `page_title` = UPPER('Surfshark Review: Should we Surf the Internet Ocean with this VPN? (2019)') AND STR_TO_DATE(`datetime`, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2019-09-16', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2019-09-22', '%Y-%m-%d') but it not working

Comment: UPPER(page_title) = UPPER(.....

Comment: Try in steps. `select * from table_name where upper(page_title) like '%SURFSHARK%'`. If this gives rows, then copy `page_title` into original query and run it again. If no rows, then you don't have any data with SURFSHARK. NOTE: I work on oracle, and seems to me you are using SQL SERVER. So add any quotes in statement, if missing

Comment: tried not working.

Comment: Please do not put code into comments. If you have additional information, **[edit]** your question by clicking on the [edit] link below it.

Comment: this is mysql he is using tick (`)

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ this is mysqli

Comment: I never worked on MYSQL or SQL Server. SO totally my bad. Thanks @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ

Comment: can anybody help me with this, please.

Comment: nothing wrong on your query, this might be data issue

Comment: What does this query return? ```SELECT * FROM `table_name` 
WHERE `page_title` = 'Surfshark Review: Should we Surf the Internet Ocean with this VPN? (2019)';```?

Comment: Please show us the underlying model for that table. Are you sure the text is in the title field, are you sure you did not misspell (or miss-charcter encoded) the example? Let's try to exclude common mistakes first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your query. It looks fine on a strict scenario... or it could be a data issue.

If you work like this.

```
SELECT....
FROM ....
WHERE  ( column like "%xxx%" )  -- a condition 
 OR 
(
  col_date BETWEEN "xxxx-xx-xx" AND "xxxx-xx-xx"   -- a condition 
   AND  anothercondition   -- a condition 
   and anothercondition     -- a condition 
)
```

Adding parenthesis and changing  AND/OR operators and between makes the difference.

For more hits you can make dynamic script for your keyword search. You can use programming to generate this part of the query.

```
       (column like "%word%" 
    OR  column like "%anotherword%" 
   OR  column like "%anotherword%" )
```